# std sigma is not the same as fspecial sigma in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

```
f1 = fspecial('gaussian', 5, 5);
```

this, in matlab, produces a 5 cross 5 matrix and the standard deviation is 5.

but when i do

```
std(f1)
```

the answers aren't around 5.

What exactly is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The std that you assigned to the `fspecial` function is not the standard deviation of value (wieght) of the output filter. Actually the output of that function is a bell-shaped distribution. To have a better idea about that, look at the following exaggerated version of your code:

```
f1 = fspecial('gaussian', 50, 5)
surf(f1)
```

[image: the bell shaped distribution (bivariate standard normal distribution)]

That standard deviation in the input arguments, is standard deviation of a sample drawn from a distribution with the bivariate standard normal PDF. And it shows the shape of the distribution, so that, the smaller value of the std leads to higher values in the centre and lower values elsewhere and a higher value of std makes a flatter shape.